Screen pixel flickering
The issue is like the following video:
https://github.com/kylehuynh205/anything/raw/refs/heads/main/screen_ubuntu.mp4

My computer info:
Lenovo Thinkpad T480  
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu  
DISTRIB_RELEASE=24.04  
DISTRIB_CODENAME=noble  
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS"  

Graphic card info: 
*-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: UHD Graphics 620
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       version: 07
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
       configuration: depth=32 driver=i915 latency=0 resolution=1920,1080
       resources: irq:164 memory:e7000000-e7ffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff ioport:e000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff

The issue appears randomly and goes away when I turn the screen off/on.
